# I have problems passing array of integers to server side

Tags: c, arrays, sockets

The first problem that occurs is that when I receive the number of integers on server side it returns the wrong value. The second problem is that I don't get the correct values of the array elements on the server side. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void)
{
    int s, s2, t, len;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;


    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;) {
        int done, n;
        printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            printf("Check Failed\n");  // to check failed
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Sequence Ok\n"); // to sequence ok


        done = 0;

        do {
            int nums;

            //Server receive number of integers
            int numbers = recv(s2, &nums, nums,0);

            int str[numbers];

            printf("###Server side: Array length is:%d\n",numbers);

            //Server receive elements of array
            int array = recv(s2,&str,numbers* sizeof(int) ,0);

            for(int i=0;i<numbers;i++)
            {
                printf("###Server side: Array element is:%d\n",str[i]);
            }

            int tmp=0;
            int avg=0;

           for(int i=0; i<*str; i++)
       {
             tmp+=str[i]; 
             printf("tmp is:%d\n",&tmp);
           }
           avg = tmp / str;
           printf("Average of numbers is:%d\n",avg);          


           if(avg>10)
           { 
                //send(s2, str, n, 0);
           }

           if (n==1) done = 1; 

        } 
    while (!done);

        close(s2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void)
{
    int s, t, len, nums, done;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    int str[100];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Trying to connect...\n");

    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) 
    {
        perror("connect");
        printf("Sequence failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Sequence Ok.\n");

    done = 0;
    do 
    {   

       printf("enter how many numbers you want to insert: ");
       scanf("%d",&nums);
       int array[nums];


       printf("Size of array is:%d\n",nums);

       for(int i=0; i<nums; i++)
       {
           scanf("%d",&array[i]);
           printf("Array[%d] = %d\n",i,array[i]);
       }



        //Send numbers of integers to server
        if (send(s, &nums, nums, 0) < 0)
        { 
            puts("Send failed"); 
            return 1; 
        }


        //Send array elements to server
        if (send(s, &array, nums* sizeof(int),0) < 0)
        {
           puts("Send failed");
           return 1;
        }




       if (t==1) done = 1;

     } while (!done);

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
Server side response:

```
Waiting for a connection...

Sequence Ok

Server side: Array length is:25

Server side: Array element is:0

Server side: Array element is:0

Server side: Array element is:1994149667

Server side: Array element is:32735

Server side: Array element is:1995560800

Server side: Array element is:32735

Server side: Array element is:-916045749

Server side: Array element is:21898

Server side: Array element is:11

Server side: Array element is:0

Server side: Array element is:1995560800

Server side: Array element is:32735

Server side: Array element is:-916045749

Server side: Array element is:21898

Server side: Array element is:1994101170

Server side: Array element is:32735

Server side: Array element is:0

Server side: Array element is:0

Server side: Array element is:-1230801088

Server side: Array element is:32765

Server side: Array element is:-1230800736

Server side: Array element is:32765

Server side: Array element is:-916049664

Server side: Array element is:21898

Server side: Array element is:-1230800512

Average of numbers is:0
```

Client side response:

```
Sequence Ok.

enter how many numbers you want to insert max(100)> 5

Size of array is:5

1

Array[0] = 1

2

Array[1] = 2

3

Array[2] = 3

4

Array[3] = 4

5

Array[4] = 5
```

**Expected output:**

Server side response:

```
Waiting for a connection...

Sequence Ok

Server side: Array length is:5

Server side: Array element is:1

Server side: Array element is:2

Server side: Array element is:3

Server side: Array element is:4

Server side: Array element is:5

Average of numbers is:3
```

Client side response:

```
Sequence Ok.

enter how many numbers you want to insert max(100)> 5

Size of array is:5

1

Array[0] = 1

2

Array[1] = 2

3

Array[2] = 3

4

Array[3] = 4

5

Array[4] = 5
```

Comment: Check what 3rd argument in recv() and send() is, then fix your code. This should help you resolve the issue with seeing "25" as an array size on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have time to look over all of the code, but what jumps out is that your first send() and recv() make no sense. It looks like you're trying to send and receive the number of integers for the subsequent transfer, which is reasonable, but

```
send(s, &nums, nums, 0);
```

sends `nums` bytes, rather than sending just the bytes that make up the number itself. It should be

```
send(s, &nums, sizeof nums, 0);
```

Likewise,

```
int numbers = recv(s2, &nums, nums,0);
```

should be

```
int result = recv(s2, &nums, sizeof nums, 0);
```

and there's no need for the extra "numbers" variable.

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer, could you demonstrate should i send and receive  an array of integers,of course  when you have free time.

Comment: You second send() and recv() (the ones that send the actual array) look OK to me.

Comment: The array in the for loop doesn't display the value of the last element correctly the code:    for(int i=0;i<=numbers;i++ )
{
   printf("###Server side: Array element is:%d\n",str[i]);
   tmp = tmp + str[i]; 
   printf("tmp is:%d\n",tmp);
}
                
avg = tmp / numbers;
printf("Average of numbers is:%d\n",avg);

Comment: `for(i=0; i<=numbers; i++)` will loop `numbers + 1` times. Try `<`. And I thought you got rid of "numbers" anyway..."nums" is the number of values.